# Out-GridView with Passthru for powershell 2?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, out-gridview

Powershell v3 added the `-Passthru` switch to the `Out-GridView` cmdlet that allows user to select items that are returned back to the pipeline.

I'm looking for a similar solution for Powershell v2 (Dotnet 3.5/4.0). I need the option to pipe in some values, allow user to filter and choose multiple values, and return the selected items to the pipeline.

Is there a way run the new `Out-GridView` throught dotnet? or maybe someone created a code for something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got this, FWIW:

[Select -Item](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Select-Item-V-10-beta-5e579fa6)

Not a real grid view, but it works for V2, and in remoting sessions where GridView isn't an option.